# Editing questions after many downvotes

Tags: discussion

How much of a change is allowed in questions that have been downvoted? I have seen the policy on editing questions with existing answers [When is an edit not an edit any more?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258/when-is-an-edit-not-an-edit-any-more) but this does not seem to apply to questions that have no answers yet.

I am new to the SE and do not yet have the hang of asking questions in the correct wording. Because of this I attract downvotes right away. Sometimes I am lucky to get a comment telling me only it was a bad question. I clearly understand they thought it was a bad question, hence the downvote. My motivation to ask the question has not changed, so I try to edit the question to better focus the scope and remove extraneous details in order to attract the knowledgeable answers.

My original question in my head is unchanged, I am only editing to more clearly communicate this in the appropriate format of the community. Can I make sweeping edits if no one has answered and there are only negative comments? Or should I just delete the question and try again?

I emphasize that I want to learn and obtain quality answers to my questions, this naturally follows from clear and concise questions.

Answer (score 8):

Of course you, as the original poster, can make large edits to an unanswered question. I'd even consider it commendable to try to make a question more suitable after downvotes.

Even after a question has answers, you can still edit your question, so long as the *spirit* of the question remains the same: you're still basically asking for the same information as before.

Comment: As long as the questions has no answers, `removal => rewriting => new post` is also an option. This might be frowned upon though, I'm not sure about what's SE compliant in this.